# MUI Appbar Menu listing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Hey so my AppBar on mobile displays a button which should list a menu of choices for a user to choose from. However, when i click the button, it list horizontally rather than vertically. I checked both my css files and the styled() functionality and it keeps listing it horizontally.

Here is the AppBar code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import FacebookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Facebook';
import MailOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MailOutlined';
import InstagramIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Instagram';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

const pages = ['About', 'Join us', 'Ministries', 'Testimonies', 'Contact'];
const MyAppBar = styled(AppBar)`
  padding: 25px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(168, 19, 0);
`;
const Logo = styled('a')`
  color: white;
  marginright: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 5px;
`;
const AppbarContent = styled('a')`
  color: white;
  marginright: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
`;
const NavContent = styled('a')`
  color: rgb(168, 19, 0);
`;
export default function Appbar() {
  // const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorElHome, setAnchorElHome] = useState(null);

  const handleOpenHome = event => {
    setAnchorElHome(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseHome = () => {
    setAnchorElHome(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MyAppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            Christian Tabernacle Church
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },paddingRight: {xs: '30px', md: '0px'} }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenHome}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon sx = {{paddingRight: {xs: '10px'}}} />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElHome}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElHome)}
              onClose={handleCloseHome}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map(page => (
                <MenuItem key={page}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">
                    <NavContent href="/en" onClick={handleCloseHome}>
                      {page}
                    </NavContent>
                  </Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Typography
              variant="h5"
              sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}
            >
              Christian Tabernacle Church
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'inherit' } }}>
            {pages.map(page => (
              <Typography key={page} variant="h6">
                <AppbarContent href="/en">{page}</AppbarContent>
              </Typography>
            ))}
          </Box>
          <Logo href="/">
            <FacebookIcon />
          </Logo>
          <Logo href="/">
            <MailOutlinedIcon />
          </Logo>
          <Logo href="/">
            <InstagramIcon />
          </Logo>
          <Button color="inherit">Donate</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </MyAppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't have any CSS files except for the files created when you run
`npx create-react-app`

[Image of Appbar displayed incorrectly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHoGi.png)

EDIT:
When I run the code with other components it  loads horizontally.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';
import Appbar from './components/Appbar';
import Main_En from './components/English/Main_En';
import Main_Sp from './components/Spanish/Main_Sp';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Leaders_En from './components/English/Leaders_En';
import Ministry_En from './components/English/Ministry_En';
import Socials_En from './components/English/Socials_En';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-container">
        <div className="content-wrap">
          <Appbar />
          <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
            <Route exact path="/en" component={Main_En} />
            <Route exact path="/en/leaders" component={Leaders_En} />
            <Route exact path="/en/ministries" component={Ministry_En} />
            <Route exact path="/en/socials" component={Socials_En} />
            <Route exact path="/sp" component={Main_Sp} />
          </Router>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Welcome.js

```
import { Button, Grid, Link, makeStyles, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import worshipImage from '../img/worship.jpg';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  background: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${worshipImage})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255, 0.4)',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: '100px 50px 50px 50px',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: '20px',
  },
}));
export default function Welcome() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.background}>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
        style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}
      >
        <div className={classes.content}>
          {/* <Typography >
            Welcome to Christian Tabernacle, Choose your Preferred Language
          </Typography> */}
          <Typography variant="h3">
            A house on fire, led by the Holy Spirit
          </Typography>
          <br />
          <Typography variant="h3">
            Una casa en llamas, dirigida por el espíritu santo
          </Typography>
          <br />
          <Typography>Pick a language</Typography>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Button size="large">
              <Link href="/en" className={classes.buttonStyle}>
                English
              </Link>
            </Button>
            <Button size="large">
              <Link href="/sp" className={classes.buttonStyle}>
                Spanish
              </Link>
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sidenote I'm migrating my code from v4 to v5 so could that be a factor to the Menu items not loading properly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (Excpet `marginright` -> it should be `margin-right`). I just copy it and throw to a codesandbox and its working perfectly. Try a forced cache reset... maybe it works.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I did more testing and when I use the component by itself it works. But when I load this with other components I get the horizontal menu

Comment: Found the issue, I had my appBar using v5 components and the Welcome page was using v4 components. Once i migrated everything to V5, everything worked seamlessly